# Showing a polynomial over $\mathbb Z$ is positive

Tags: inequality, polynomials, integer-programming

I want to show that the polynomial,

$$(2c+1)(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1)(a/2+d-2c)(2+a/2-d+2c)-(b-2c+2d-1)(2c+1-d)^2$$

is greater than zero, for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z$ subject to the constraints:

- $a \mod 4 = 0$
- $b \geq a/2$
- $c \leq a/4-1$
- $d \leq 2c$

and note $a,b,c,d$ are bounded from below by zero. Since this isn't a real polynomial, I can't just prove the non-existence of real roots to establish that the polynomial $> 0$.

I would appreciate any help, but please **do not post a full solution**. Note also this arose from original work, and the form the polynomial is written is thus not any hint to a solution.

If I am not mistaken, one observation I made that may be useful is given the constraints none of the terms in brackets are ever negative.

Comment: @WillJagy you can't have $b = 2c$. Take for example $a = 8$, then $b \geq 4$ and $c \leq 1$.

Comment: it works, out of your product of five (nonnegative) terms  minus things, both terms $(2c+1)$  and $(2 + \frac{a}{2}  + 2c - d)$ are at least as large as $(2c+1-d),$  that being the term you are squaring. Then $(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1) \geq (b-2c + 2d - 1).$  So the whole thing is nonnegative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(2c+1)(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1)(a/2+d-2c)(2+a/2-d+2c)-(b-2c+2d-1)(2c+1-d)^2$$

We want
$$(2c+1)(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1)(\frac{a}{2}+d-2c)(2+\frac{a}{2}-d+2c) \geq(b-2c+2d-1)(2c+1-d)^2$$

as $ c \leq \frac{a}{4} -1,$ we get $ 2c \leq \frac{a}{2} -2,$ with $ -2c \geq 2- \frac{a}{2} .$  Since $ b \geq  \frac{a}{2} .$  we reach
$$  b-2c \geq 2.  $$  It follows that
$$(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1) \geq 2(b-2c) + 2d - 2, $$
$$(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1) \geq (b-2c) + 2d  + (b-2c) -2 , $$
$$(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1) \geq (b-2c) + 2d  \geq (b-2c+2d-1). $$
$$ \color{blue}{(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1) } \geq (b-2c+2d-1). $$

Next we see
$$  \color{blue}{ (2c+1)}  \geq (2c+1 - d), $$
$$ \color{blue}{ (2+\frac{a}{2}-d+2c) } \geq (2c+1 - d). $$

Mix in our three inequalities, we find
$$(2c+1)(b-2c)(b-2c+d-1)(\frac{a}{2}+d-2c)(2+\frac{a}{2}-d+2c) \geq(b-2c+2d-1)(2c+1-d)^2$$

Comment: Thanks. Your comment was adequate but appreciate the detail in the answer.